# UI Components library for react native

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, react-native

I'm building my first big app with react native.
And want to ask.

Are there are some UI frameworks for react native, which gives some styling for components out of the box?

For example like ionic for cordova gives base theme and css.
Or like bootstrap for web.

So are there are some existing libraries which gives the same styling effect for react native?

Thanks

Comment: One library you might want to take a look at is the [RN Material Kit](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit).

Answer (score 12):

There are some other UI toolkits that allows a developer to style components with ease something like that of ionic and bootstrap. These toolkits support both iOS and Android

**1. Nativebase**

[nativebase.io](http://nativebase.io/)

> Single JavaScript code base for iOS & Android with custom components like Button, Toolbar (Header/Footer), Input (with Icons)

**2. Shoutem**

[shoutem.github.io](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction)

> Shoutem UI toolkit enables you to build professionally looking React Native apps with ease.

Answer (score 8):

There are several, these are the most complete ones:

[Shoutem](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction)

[React Native Material Kit](http://www.xinthink.com/react-native-material-kit/)

[Native Base](https://nativebase.io/)

[React Native Elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements)

[Kitten Tricks](https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks)

[React Native Material Design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design)

[Teaset](https://github.com/rilyu/teaset)

[Nachos UI](https://avocode.com/nachos-ui/)

[Panza](https://github.com/panza-org/panza)

[React Native UI Kit](https://github.com/andyfen/react-native-uikit)

[Ignite](https://infinite.red/ignite)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of material libraries out there:

http://react-native-material-design.github.io/

http://mrn.js.org/

Also recently saw someone released a bootstrap for react native:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootstrap

Comment: are there are something for ios?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though some of the native components such as the picker, datepicker, and activity indicator come with iOS styling out of the box .